# Pull files from GitHub repository from code and render on webpage

Tags: php, git, api, github, github-api

I'm looking for a way to display webpage contents by directly pulling updated content from a GitHub repository (perhaps by using an API). The content can be any file format ranging from plain text to images, and I'd like to render the same in an HTML webpage according a certain layout, and am wondering if the GitHub PHP API can be used to achieve this. Any insights would be appreciated, I'm just a little unsure of where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the GitHub API can do is trigger a script on your server whenever there is a [push event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent).

Those are **[webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/)**, and require for your server to have a listener (a process listening to the push even [JSON payload](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#payloads))

That listener process would then call a script (on your server) which would then:

- pull from the GitHub repo
- apply any post-processing it has to do (like rendering some template files with the right value)
- copy those rendered files to the right tree, for your HTTP server to display them.

As you can see, the role of the GitHub API is fairly limited here.